# How do I send messages to a messagequeue using rabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm trying to send messages to a rabbitmq server however I can't find any documentation on how to do this in c#, it only tells you how to do it in python, and I would like some help on this.

thanks =]

Answer (score 0):

You should download the [c# AMQP client from here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html).
There is comprehensive documentation inside the download package.

You can also download just the [PDF User guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.1.1/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.1.1-user-guide.pdf).  This provides documentation on how to use the client C# API.

Also, if you have the option, the [EasyNetQ](http://easynetq.com/) project provides a very easy programming model around the base C# AMQP client.  It is worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

See this (general info)

http://www.rabbitmq.com

And this for .Net

http://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet.html

For instance, API

http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html

Tutorial (Java and Python)

http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html

UserGuide (C#)

http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.1.1/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.1.1-user-guide.pdf